# Как управлять одним mediaplayer во всем приложении

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, android-mediaplayer

У меня есть mediaplayer в mainActivity , который не отключается при переходе, но выключается при нажатии на кнопку home, из main я это сделал, но как управлять этим же mediaplayer в других activity, если вообще можно?

Comment: Можно попробовать запускать service с mediaPlayer. Рекомендую вам почитать про сервисы в android.

Comment: @igo не можно, а нужно.